# Unable to extract value from below json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

I have below JSON response from the request. I want to extract value term_no from the ticket list key json response. Tried using json path finder and not getting the correct value. Could some one help me to get the correct output.

Json Response

```
   {
  "data": {
    "action": "vcvc",
    "method": "xcxcx",
    "content": "{\"action\":\"wdsds\",\"ticket_version\":\"23343\",\"payment_version\":\"3323\",\"purchase_version\":\"5656\",\"responselist\":[{\"seq_no\":\"1000466303\",\"bank_resp_code\":\"0\",\"transid\":\"27344650\",\"auth_code\":\"123456\",\"amount\":\"210\",\"paymethod_id\":\"*****\",\"payment_no\":\"\"}],\"ticketlist\":[{\"seq_no\":\"1000882730\",\"trx_no\":\"83149\",\"term_no\":\"2001\",\"sale_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_amount\":\"210\",\"start_validity\":\"20240127025741\",\"end_validity\":\"20250126025741\",\"tt_id\":\"12010\",\"printed_serial_number\":\"8706\",\"trx_seq_id\":\"1100430687\",\"bus_zone\":\"9\",\"active_ticket_duration\":\"165\",\"exception_data\":\"\",\"zip_code\":\"07001\"},{\"seq_no\":\"1000882731\",\"trx_no\":\"83149\",\"term_no\":\"2001\",\"sale_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_amount\":\"0\",\"start_validity\":\"xxxxx\",\"end_validity\":\"20250126025741\",\"tt_id\":\"12010\",\"printed_serial_number\":\"xxx\",\"trx_seq_id\":\"xxxxxx\",\"bus_zone\":\"x\",\"active_ticket_duration\":\"xxx\",\"exception_data\":\"\",\"zip_code\":\"07001\"}],\"status_msg\":\"Success\",\"status_code\":\"0\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"site_id\":\"1_N\",\"term_no\":\"2001\"}",
    "status_msg": "Success",
    "status_code": "0",
    "version": "1.0",
    "site_id": "1_N"
  }
}
```

Used below way

```
    pm.test("The response has all properties", () => {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
      pm.expect(responseJson.data.content.ticketlist[0].term_no).to.eql('2001');
       

});
```

Getting the below Error

**The response has all properties |  JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2 [object Object]**

Comment: That's not valid json.  Look at the the `content` node.  It starts off as `content: "{"action":"",....`   Is content a string or an object?  If it's a string then it's the string `"{"` followed by invalid tokens.  If it's an object it needs to lose the quotes around it.

Comment: Is there any way we can get term_no value?

Comment: Also, all your field names need to be quoted if that's a json string. And if it's an already parsed json object, then `content` is malformed.

Comment: posted correct json, could please check once

Comment: And updated again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer after doing this getting below error nowpm.test("The response has all properties", () => {
    const responseJson =JSON.parse(pm.response);
  pm.expect(responseJson.data.content.ticketlist[0].term_no).to.eql('2001');

});
The response has all properties | JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2 [object Object]

Comment: Add a `console.log(pm.response);` line first. What does it print out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(pm.response).data.content).ticketlist[0].term_no`

Comment: If i use above line getting below error                                                                  
JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2 [object Object] ^

Comment: console log giving the same output which i posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` of the `data` is a JSON string. You will need to parse it, prior to accessing the inner `ticketlist` array.

```js
const pm = testSuite();

pm.test("The response has all properties", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  const content = JSON.parse(responseJson.data.content); // Parse JSON string
  pm.expect(content.ticketlist[0].term_no).to.eql('2001');
});

function testSuite() {
  return {
    response: {
      json: () => ({
        "data": {
          "action": "vcvc",
          "method": "xcxcx",
          "content": "{\"action\":\"wdsds\",\"ticket_version\":\"23343\",\"payment_version\":\"3323\",\"purchase_version\":\"5656\",\"responselist\":[{\"seq_no\":\"1000466303\",\"bank_resp_code\":\"0\",\"transid\":\"27344650\",\"auth_code\":\"123456\",\"amount\":\"210\",\"paymethod_id\":\"*****\",\"payment_no\":\"\"}],\"ticketlist\":[{\"seq_no\":\"1000882730\",\"trx_no\":\"83149\",\"term_no\":\"2001\",\"sale_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_amount\":\"210\",\"start_validity\":\"20240127025741\",\"end_validity\":\"20250126025741\",\"tt_id\":\"12010\",\"printed_serial_number\":\"8706\",\"trx_seq_id\":\"1100430687\",\"bus_zone\":\"9\",\"active_ticket_duration\":\"165\",\"exception_data\":\"\",\"zip_code\":\"07001\"},{\"seq_no\":\"1000882731\",\"trx_no\":\"83149\",\"term_no\":\"2001\",\"sale_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_no\":\"1\",\"ticket_amount\":\"0\",\"start_validity\":\"xxxxx\",\"end_validity\":\"20250126025741\",\"tt_id\":\"12010\",\"printed_serial_number\":\"xxx\",\"trx_seq_id\":\"xxxxxx\",\"bus_zone\":\"x\",\"active_ticket_duration\":\"xxx\",\"exception_data\":\"\",\"zip_code\":\"07001\"}],\"status_msg\":\"Success\",\"status_code\":\"0\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"site_id\":\"1_N\",\"term_no\":\"2001\"}",
          "status_msg": "Success",
          "status_code": "0",
          "version": "1.0",
          "site_id": "1_N"
        }
      })
    },
    test(description, callback) {
      console.log(`[Test] ${description}`);
      callback();
    },
    expect(actualValue) {
      return {
        to: {
          eql(expectedValue) {
            if (actualValue !== expectedValue) {
              throw new Error(`[Fail] Actual value '${actualValue}' does not match expected value '${expectedValue}'`);
            }
          }
        }
      };
    },
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The content field itself is JSON string encoded into another json string.  So we just need to decode that again after the initial decode.

If `responseJson` is an already parsed json string converted into object, then this is what you want:

```
var term_no = JSON.parse(responseJson.data.content).ticketlist[0].term_no;
```

If `responseJson` is the raw string from the server that needs to be parsed into an object, then this:

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(responseJson);
var term_no = JSON.parse(responseObj.data.content).ticketlist[0].term_no;
```

And I just noticed you are trying to read `ticketlist` off of `action`. That's not the hierarchy of your object. So if `responseJson` is fully parsed, you might have meant this:

Also of note, your code here:

```
pm.expect(responseJson.data.content.action['0'].ticketlist.term_no).to.eql('2001');
```

Wouldn't work even if responseJson was fully parsed. It would be this:

```
pm.expect(responseJson.data.content.ticketlist[0].term_no).to.eql('2001');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the content object being a string.  So you will need to parse the initial JSON response using the pm.response.json() function, and then use JSON.parse to parse the content string.

```js
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

pm.test("term_no eqls 2001", () => {
    let content = JSON.parse(responseJson.data.content)
    pm.expect(content.ticketlist[0].term_no).to.eql('2001');
});
```

Why you have two objects in the ticketlist array with nearly identical information is another question completely.